# Test if vector valued functions is increasing?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Edited in response to @Randall's question, although I'm still not sure if this question makes sense.

I am trying to find out whether there exists a simple way to tell if a function from $\quad{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}^n$ is strictly increasing. For example, with functions from $\quad{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$, I would take the first derivative and try to show that it is positive on the interval I'm interested in.

In higher dimensions, the function would have to be from $\quad{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}^n$ so that the input and output vectors would be of the same dimensions. Then (as I understand it) the function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to
\mathbb{R}^n$ is strictly increasing if for all $\mathbf{x_1}, \mathbf{x_2} \in \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbf{x_1} \gt\gt \mathbf{x_2}$, we have $ \mathbf{y_1}=f(\mathbf{x_1}) \gt\gt \mathbf{y_2}=f(\mathbf{x_2})$, where $\mathbf{x_1} \gt\gt \mathbf{x_2}$ means that each component of $ \mathbf{x_1}$ is greater than than the corresponding component of $\mathbf{x_2}$.

Is there a test like looking at the first derivative, but in higher dimensions? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What would this even mean?  What's the ordering on points in the plane?

Comment: @Randall I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: There is no such notion of increasing function in higher dimensions because there is no sensible $\leq$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, my answer should provide a sufficient condition. If $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ is differentiable, then it is increasing if
$$
\frac {\partial f_j(\xi)}{\partial x_i} \ge 0 \quad\text{for all $i,j=1,2,\dots,n$} 
$$
and all vectors $\xi\in \Bbb R^n$. You can replace the $\ge$ sign with $>$ if you want your function to be strictly increasing.

The proof that this works is as follows: Suppose that $\mathbf x<<\mathbf y$ then each component of $\mathbf v=\mathbf y -\mathbf x$ is greater than zero. By the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$\begin{align}
f(\mathbf y) &= f(\mathbf x) + \left(\int_0^1 Df(\mathbf x + t\mathbf v) \,dt\right)\mathbf v.
\end{align}$$
The above means that for each $j$ we have
$$\begin{align}
f_j(\mathbf y) - f_j(\mathbf x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \int_0^1\frac {\partial f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf v)}{\partial x_i}\, v_i  \,dt \ge 0
\end{align}$$
by our assumption on the derivatives of $f$.

Comment: This was my intuition - thank you very much for the response and particularly for the proof! I'll go through it in detail to make sure I understand it.

Comment: Sorry I was being careless with the MVT, I changed it to FTC instead.